# How to add parameters to httprequest in order to work with twitter api 1.1

Tags: android, api, authentication, httpurlconnection, twitter-oauth

I'm working on a project (use twitter api to search for a specific HashTag)
when going into this site https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=liverpool&count=20 to get the response

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

after that I know that I should register my app in order to get Consumer Key,Consumer Secret,Access Token,Access Token Secret but I don't know how to add this tokens into my android code in order to
this is my makehttpconnection method and I want to add this tokens to the connection

```
private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
    String jsonResponse = "";

    // If the URL is null, then return early.
    if (url == null) {
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        // If the request was successful (response code 200),
        // then read the input stream and parse the response.
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the earthquake JSON results.", e);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

Note:it's unavailable for me to use Twitter sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do only timeline searches, the Application-only authentication (https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) should be fine for you.
So as a first step, register a new twitter application.
https://apps.twitter.com/

You will need a bearer token:

```
public class TwitterAuthorization extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
String returnEntry;
boolean finished;

private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "yourKey";
private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "yourSecret";
public static String bearerToken;
public static String tokenType;

private static final String tokenUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";

public void sendPostRequestToGetBearerToken () {
    URL loc = null;
    HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
    InputStreamReader is;
    BufferedReader in;

    try {
        loc = new URL(tokenUrl);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        return;
    }

    try {

        String urlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_KEY, "UTF-8");
        String urlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_SECRET, "UTF-8");
        String combined = urlApiKey + ":" + urlApiSecret;
        byte[] data = combined.getBytes();
        String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);

        conn = (HttpsURLConnection)loc.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "api.twitter.com");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "1");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "29");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        String urlParameters = "grant_type=client_credentials";

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);

        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        is = new InputStreamReader (conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        in = new BufferedReader (is);

        readResponse (in);

        setJSONresults();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {

    }
    finally {
        conn.disconnect();

    }

}


public void readResponse(BufferedReader in) {
    String tmp = "";
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    do {
        try {
            tmp = in.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        if (tmp != null) {
            response.append(tmp);
        }
    } while (tmp != null);
    returnEntry = response.toString();
}

public void setJSONresults(){
    try {
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(returnEntry);
        bearerToken =obj1.getString("access_token");
        myLog += bearerToken;

        tokenType = obj1.getString("token_type");
        myLog += tokenType;
    } catch (JSONException ex){

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    finished = true;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    finished = false;
    if (bearerToken == null) {
        sendPostRequestToGetBearerToken();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Then you can run the queries with your token:

```
private String fetchTimelineTweet(String endPointUrl) throws IOException, ParseException {
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String testUrl = " https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=&geocode=-22.912214,-43.230182,1km&lang=pt&result_type=recent&count=3";
    try {

        URL url = new URL(testUrl);
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        JSONObject jsonObjectDocument = new JSONObject(twitterAuthorizationData);
        String token = jsonObjectDocument.getString("token_type") + " "
                + jsonObjectDocument.getString("access_token");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "api.twitter.com");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
        connection.connect();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }

        setJSONObjectResults();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid endpoint URL specified.", e);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return new String();
}

public void setJSONObjectResults(){
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        JSONArray statuses;
        statuses = obj.getJSONArray("statuses");
        for (int i=0; i < statuses.length(); i++){
            String text = statuses.getJSONObject(i).getString("text");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        myLog += e.toString();
    }

}
```

You can also have a look over here, but I found it a bit of outdated.
[android: how to get trends from twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504566/android-how-to-get-trends-from-twitter)

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I'm a bit confused about something: in the code of the method sendPostRequestToGetBearerToken() we use conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); but when I debug the code I found that the method is automatically converted into "GET".                                 I also have a question about  conn.setDoInput(true); conn.setDoOutput(true); what does these two methods exactly do?

Comment: I don't really know the answer for the first part of your question, but if anyone know I'd love to hear it. According to the documentation: HttpURLConnection.setDoOutput: "Optionally upload a request body. Instances must be configured with setDoOutput(true) if they include a request body. " HttpURLConnection.setDoInput: HttpURLConnection uses the GET method by default. It will use POST if setDoOutput(true) has been called. [https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) Hope that helps